# How can I print the HTML of a webpage using WKWebView?

Tags: swift, web-scraping, wkwebview

I want to retrieve all the HTML of [a webpage](https://thehill.com/homenews/media/454838-cnn-announces-climate-town-hall-with-2020-democrats) using WKWebView, but it doesn't give me the right result.  How would I make a function so that all the HTML is correctly scraped?

So far, this is what I did:

```
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", 
                           completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
    print(html)
})
```

Only thing I get is `Optional(<html><head></head><body></body></html>)`

Comment: Why use a `WKWebView`? If you want the HTML then why not download the page from the URL?

Comment: Well, this is kind of unrelated, but I want to scrape websites and extract the main text from the HTML code but since some websites use JavaScript or don't use the <p> tag, it's very hard to get the text using tools like SwiftSoup. So I was hoping that extracting text using WKWebView would help.